# Fixed header Row in Sharepoint2010 List and deployment

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hei
I want to fix the header columns of sharepoint list in administration interface by following link 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/freeze-header-row-and-first-columns-in-a-list

I intend to add above "hack" in v4.master. so we can overwrite v4.master during deployment? but the problem is we cannot overwrite v4.master then this can be updated by Microsoft when a new service pack is installed. Can anyone have tips how can we achieve this and deploy too .